# Adding Command Button allowing user to view hidden sheet

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

I am new to using Macros/VB in excel and in need of some help (in the simplest way you can instruct me)

I have a workbook with two sheets. I have already created a form on sheet 1 which will allow users to enter data which then is populated within a hidden sheet (sheet2).

I would like to add a button on sheet 1 for the user to view the hidden "list data" they have entered in sheet 2 but they cannot be able to edit the data - only view it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't it be a lot easier to protect sheet 2 with a password to prevent them from editing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For tips on writing great questions visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you have any questions about the site, you can visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) or visit [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a shape (I prefer this over an ActiveX control) on the sheet with your form. I named the shape "Show data" and gave that same caption to the button. Now add the following code to a standard code module (one which VBE names like "Module1").

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowData_Click()
    ' 25 Jul 2017

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jeanette")
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Change the name of the worksheet with the data to the name you have given that sheet in your project. Then right-click on the button (shape) and select "Assign macro". Assign the "ShowData_Click" macro. Now, when you click the button the hidden sheet will become visible and be activated.

In the code sheet for the data sheet (which is normally hidden), add the following to procedures.

```
Option Explicit

    Dim ThisSheet As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 25 Jul 2017
    ThisSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    ' 25 Jul 2017
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets(ThisSheet).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub
```

The first one will run whenever the sheet is activated which happens when the new button is pressed. It will remember the name of the sheet. This is so that you don't need to hard-code the name.

The second procedure will run whenever you activate another sheet in the workbook. It will hide the sheet again. So, you show the sheet by pressing the button and hide the sheet by selecting another sheet.

I'm not a friend of Excel's protection. So, I suggest another way to prevent users from modifying the data. Here is the code. Install it on the same code sheet where you already have the Activate and Deactivate procedures.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 25 Jul 2017

    Static ShowMsg As Integer

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
        ShowMsg = ShowMsg + 1
        If (ShowMsg Mod 3) = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Data in this sheet may not be modified." & vbCr & _
                   "Your changes have been removed.", _
                   vbInformation, "Invalid action"
        End If
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

This code will undo any change the user makes. The user will receive a message to this effect each third time he/she tries to modify something.